# How can i "attach" nvidia gpu card to xp vm in vmware?

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, vmware, nvidia, device-driver

I have an old Nvidia gpu card that basically goes unused on my host. So i wanted to attach it to a VMware vm ( Win XP ) and use it the same way i can use a usb stick. How difficult is it to write a device driver to hook VMW's API with Nvidia's API? What open source device drivers are there to do this? Its not for graphics processing but splitting parallel computations up to run faster, hence Mesa project not the right direction...

Comment: It appears VIX does NOT give you the ability to "Attach" or "Detach" any devices to vm's, altho VDDK appears to make virtual disks available to vm's

Comment: Obviously its not that simple, I also need to be able to suspend & resume when the vm is.

Comment: My "new" use for this tensorflow.org using GPU's to speed things up. See VMware's Horizon 7 pdf vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmware-horizon-view-graphics-acceleration-deployment.pdf